# Lumen with Dingo API routes not defined

Tags: laravel, lumen, dingo-api

Have a fresh install of Lumen 5.2 and new install of Dingo 1.0.*@dev

I have installed the service provided in bootstrap/app.php

Also setup .env file eg

```
API_VERSION=v1
API_PREFIX=api
API_SUBTYPE=app
API_DEBUG=true
```

In the Http/routes.php I have added a test route eg

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');


$api->version('v1', ['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\V1'], function ($api) {
    $api->get('example', 'ExampleController@test');
});
```

This route is not working plus in command line if I try `php artisan api:routes`

I get error

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "api:routes" is not defined.                            
  Did you mean this?                                              
      api:docs
```

Have I missed something? Also using HTTP Basic if it helps?

Answer (score 5):

In Dingo Documentation -> Creating API Endpoints section you can find this sentence:

"If you're using Laravel 5.1 you can see the registered routes using Artisan.

```
$ php artisan api:routes
```

"

If you also run

```
$ php artisan list
```

only api:docs is available - api:routes is missing.

That means that this command do not work in Lumen.

Answer (score 0):

composer requires `jakubkratina/lumen-dingo-route-list`

Add the following code in  `app/Console/Kernel.php`:

```php
    protected $commands = [
        \JK\Dingo\Api\Console\Commands\RouteListCommand::class
    ];
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, as shown in docs, lumen don't ship with `api:routes`. But you can use [lumen-dingo-route-list](https://github.com/jakubkratina/lumen-dingo-route-list) from jakubkratina. It will add `route:list` to your artisan.

By the way, I'd to do some adjustments to get it working:

First, include the backlash into the registration

```
    protected $commands = [
        \JK\Dingo\Api\Console\Commands\RouteListCommand::class
    ];
```

And last, edit `vendor/jakubkratina/lumen-dingo-route-list/src/RouteListCommand.php` and add this code:

```
public function handle()
{
    return $this->fire();
}
```